# Advanced Excel Table Sorting

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to sort my spreadsheet as follows:

[image: Excel Table]

The overall sorting criteria is based on the WAREHOUSE, BAY LOCATION and SHELF IF the product has been designated "YES" in the PICKING Column. You will notice the text in red is sorted alphabetically in ascending order by WAREHOUSE then by BAY LOCATION.

HOWEVER I need to find all other warehouse locations that match the PRODUCT CODE and display that data underneath that same PRODUCT CODE but this data must be sorted by BBD and then display the WAREHOUSE, BAY LOCATION and SHELF.

This spreadsheet is to help with Best Before Date rotation in a Warehouse that stores Candy. It will allow people to walk around the warehouse bay by bay and have a printed out sheet that displays the picking bay locations sorted in the location they appear in that warehouse while also displaying all the other locations that same product is stored in various other warehouses ordered by BBD.

I do not know what road to go down to achieve this solution. VBA? Pivot Table? or can it be achieved through functions?

Comment: Could you share some relevant 'messed-up' sample data (the initial data) as text? Your screenshot shows that the data should be sorted by *BBD* or *Bay Location*, and then by *Product* (not quite).

Comment: Apologies, im not sure I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it correctly you mean to first sort the products that are set to picking = "YES" based on the Warehouse / Bay Location / Shelf in ascending order, but keep the picking = "No" lines underneath the same product code lines and have them sorted on the BBD / Warehouse / Bay Location / Shelf.

We could do this in Microsoft 365 using the following formula:

```
=LET(d, A2:F10,
     o, HSTACK(d,XMATCH(INDEX(d,,1),
                        TAKE(SORT(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(d,3,4,5,1),INDEX(d,,6)="YES"),{1,2,3,4}),,-1))),
DROP( 
     SORT(o,
           {7,6,2,3,4,5},
           {1,-1,1,1,1,1}),
     ,-1))
```

[image]

Explanation:
I changed you sample data to be in random order and changed one of the warehouses for the picking `Yes` type, to demonstrate the filter order better:

unsorted data:

| Product Code | BBD | Warehouse | Bay Location | Shelf | Picking |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Scooters | 03/03/2023 | 7 | C01 | 3 | No |
| Bikes | 01/01/2023 | 6 | A02 | 1 | YES |
| Buggy | 01/01/2023 | 8 | A03 | 1 | YES |
| Bikes | 02/02/2023 | 9 | B02 | 3-4 | No |
| Scooters | 02/02/2023 | 6 | B02 | 2-3 | No |
| Buggy | 03/03/2023 | 4 | C03 | 3 | No |
| Scooters | 01/01/2023 | 8 | A01 | 1 | YES |
| Bikes | 03/03/2023 | 8 | C02 | 4 | No |
| Buggy | 02/02/2023 | 5 | B03 | 3 | No |

In this example the following lines are Picking "Yes":

| Product Code | BBD | Warehouse | Bay Location | Shelf | Picking |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bikes | 01/01/2023 | 6 | A02 | 1 | YES |
| Buggy | 01/01/2023 | 8 | A03 | 1 | YES |
| Scooters | 01/01/2023 | 8 | A01 | 1 | YES |

As you want these sorted ascending based on the Warehouse / Bay Location / Shelf, this will set the order:

| Product Code | Order | explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bikes | 1 | warehouse 6<8 |
| Scooters | 2 | Bay A01<A03 |
| Buggy | 3 | Bay A03>A01 |

If we than lookup the product codes of the table in this order matrix and append the results to the table, this would make:

| Product Code | BBD | Warehouse | Bay Location | Shelf | Picking | Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Scooters | 03/03/2023 | 7 | C01 | 3 | No | 2 |
| Bikes | 01/01/2023 | 6 | A02 | 1 | YES | 1 |
| Buggy | 01/01/2023 | 8 | A03 | 1 | YES | 3 |
| Bikes | 02/02/2023 | 9 | B02 | 3-4 | No | 1 |
| Scooters | 02/02/2023 | 6 | B02 | 2-3 | No | 2 |
| Buggy | 03/03/2023 | 4 | C03 | 3 | No | 3 |
| Scooters | 01/01/2023 | 8 | A01 | 1 | YES | 2 |
| Bikes | 03/03/2023 | 8 | C02 | 4 | No | 1 |
| Buggy | 02/02/2023 | 5 | B03 | 3 | No | 3 |

We can then use this last column in the sort criteria, to keep similar product codes together and still have the picking lines be sorted based on the other criteria.

Comment: Yes you understood correctly. Thank you! I realise now that having the sample data as text allows you to manipulate and test without having to manually enter in the contents. Sorry for the confusion. I will test this formula out and see how It goes. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Again fantastic work on this solution. I spent some time studying your formula to understand it. Eventually worked out the solution was all about manipulating the different arrays and those arrays that were created were then used within other functions. Was slightly confused with all the functions nested within functions but just took the time to break it down. For anyone looking to display data within their spreadsheet in whatever way they want, a understanding of all those functions used would be invaluable.

Comment: It's good to hear you don't only use it, but also examined the logic being used.